# Cannot get to edit view to modify profile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, path

trying to edit user profile:

in _footer (link_to "Edit profile", edit_user_path):

```
<% if current_user %>
    <% if admin? %>
      <%= link_to "Admin Page", admin_users_path %> Signed in as <%= current_user.username %> <%= link_to "Edit profile", edit_user_path %>(<%= link_to "Log out", session_path("current"), method: :delete %>) etc
```

in Users controller:

```
 def edit
    @user = current_user
    end
```

in user edit view:

```
    <%= form_for @user do |f| %>
      <% if @user.errors.any? %>
etc
```

routes:

```
resources :users, only: [:new, :create, :edit]
```

i'm obviously missing some key concept, points to another controller altogether: ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Movies#index,

No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"users"} missing required keys: [:id]

just wondering how this is wrong, thanks!

Comment: found a good tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is mentioned above. No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"users"} **missing required keys: [:id]**
You got to pass an user id to it.

```
<%= link_to "Edit profile", edit_user_path(current_user) %>
```

Comment: Thanks to both!   After a bit of sleep I realize l also should have opened up the user resource.

Answer (score 0):

> ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Movies#index,
>
> No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"users"} missing
>   required keys: [:id]

The `edit_user_path` expects an `:id` as key, so you need to pass it. The below should work

```
<%= link_to "Edit profile", edit_user_path(current_user) %>
```